# With Office 365 Excel Online, Edge iPadoS 17.1.1, how to reference this Workbook from separate Workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, file-sharing, web, reference-book

I need help to reference separate Workbook using Excel 365 Home Online on ipadOS 17.1.1.
Following steps worked for Windows desktop but not in with Office 365 Excel Online.

1. open two instances of Excel Mobile
2. Open a workbook A in instance 1
3. Open a workbook B in instance 2
4. In cell of Workbook A, type in equal Sign
5. Then click on Workbook B cell